# DjVu reader for Mac

Tags: osx, image-viewer, djvu

I am looking for a fast, convenient and reliable [DjVu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu) reader application for OS X.

Requirements:

- responsive continuous scrolling
- must be standalone (*not* browser plugin)
- retina support

I.e. something that could replace Preview for DjVu files.

Gratis software preferred but not required.  I do not want to spend money on anything until I am certain that it works well (I've already had a bad experience with one I bought and turned out to be useless).

---

I am still looking for answers.  DjView now has retina support and better responsiveness than before (only with Qt5 builds), but it still lags behind other viewers in page rendering and scrolling performance.

Comment: Someone added the `image-viewer` tag, which is technically correct, but I wanted to make it clear that DjVu files are multi-page and used like PDFs in practice, not like usual image files.  So any specialized image viewers such as XnView are unlikely to be useful unless they've been specifically optimized for browsing multi-page documents.

Comment: Also, properly rendered DJVU file *will* contain a hidden text layer making it possible to search a file for a specific text string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of all (scarce) DJVU viewing software for OSX i so far find [DJView](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) the most feature rich among gratis software.

- *responsive continuous scrolling* - Check
- *must be standalone (not browser plugin)* - Check
- *retina support* - No check

Other functions that I find very useful:

- searching for text string if the text layer is present and copy text string into other applications
- side by side page view
- invert luminance (white text on black background)

---

**2016 update:** There are now Qt5-based builds of DjView. These are much more responsive than the Qt4-based builds and have retina support.  As of June 2016, the Sourceforge build is Qt5-based.  With MacPorts, be sure to install `djview-qt5` and not `djview`.

Comment: I typed `brew cask install djview` in MacOS's terminal, which got me DjVuLibre DjView 4.10.6 with Qt-5.7.0 (Jan 2019).